# Represent a graph containing directed and undirected edges using List<Integer>

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, graph

I was asked this question in one of my google interviews. I couldn't figure it out. If someone can help that would be great :)

The class provided was

```
class Node{
   int data,
   List<Node> outEdges;
}
```

if you're provided a Node stream containing both directed and undirected edges you have to encode it in such a way that it return List and and decode again to original graph

```
List<Integer> encode(Node root){
}

Node decode(List<Integer> graph){
}
```

The hint provided was you can add your own integers if you want

Comment: Well, there a many ways to encode a graph to a list. One might be to basically define a structure for the list, e.g. you could put pairs into the list that describe an edge, e.g. `1,2,2,1,2,3` could mean a graph like `1<->2->3`. You could also add a 3rd value that's basically a boolean describing whether the edge is directed or not, e.g. the example graph could also be returned as `1,1,2,0,2,3`. Doing this could save some space if there are more undirected than directed edges.

Comment: we also should represent the correct direction between 2 edges. I gave this solution we would put 1 if there is a direct edge and -1 if its opposite and 0 for undirected. But how should we traverse the root node. can you complete those methods?

Comment: Also we don't have no of nodes information

Comment: Well, in case of a directed edge you also use the convention of putting the source node first and the target node second, e.g. `1,2,3` would mean `2->3` while `1,3,2` would mean `3->2` but using 1 and -1 for the direction is fine too.

Comment: The root could just be added as the first element in the list as well as the number of nodes. However, assuming that all nodes must be connected to the graph you don't actually need that, just extract that information from the decoded graph.

Comment: Shouldn't it be List<Node> outEdges? Otherwise it doesn't make any sense to me. It is ambiguous.

Comment: @maraca yes your are right. My bad. Edited

Answer (score 1):

You could just put the data and all the edges in the list and using null as delimiter:

```
private class IndexAndEdge {
    public Set<Integer> edges = new HashSet<>();
    public int index;
    public int data;
}

List<Integer> encode(Node root) {
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    Map<Node, IndexAndEdge> lookup = new HashMap<>();
    parse(root, lookup);
    result.add(lookup.size());
    lookup.values().stream()
        .sorted((a, b) -> Integer.compare(a.index, b.index))
        .forEach(iae -> {
            result.add(iae.data);
            result.addAll(iae.edges);
            result.add(null);
        });
    result.remove(result.size() - 1);
    return result;
}

private int parse(Node node, Map<Node, IndexAndEdge> lookup) {
    if (lookup.containsKey(node))
        return lookup.get(node).index;
    IndexAndEdge iae = new IndexAndEdge();
    iae.index = lookup.size();
    iae.data = node.data;
    lookup.put(node, iae);
    for (Node n : node.outEdges)
        iae.edges.add(parse(n, lookup));
    return iae.index;
}

Node decode(List<Integer> graph) {
    Node[] nodes = new Node[graph.get(0)];
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        nodes[i] = new Node();
        nodes[i].outEdges = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < graph.size(); i++) {
        Integer n = graph.get(i);
        if (n == null)
            index++;
        else if (nodes[index].outEdges.isEmpty())
            nodes[index].data = n;
        else
            nodes[index].outEdges.add(nodes[n]);
    }
    return nodes[0];
}
```